# How do I install the Hamster applet?

Tags: 11.04, panel, applet

I want to add Hamster applet to my Ubuntu 11.04 installation, I am not able to right click panel and add applet to it.

Please let me know the exact method.

Sorry, But I am novice to linux.

Mandar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unity Panel ([Unity](http://unity.ubuntu.com/) is new interface for Ubuntu 11.04 with new top panel) doesn't support applets for GNOME Panel.

You can use Hamster Indicator (package `hamster-indicator`) from Alberto Milone's PPA repository

`ppa:albertomilone/hamster-indicator`

More information here:

- http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/install-hamster-indicator-time-tracking.html
- http://albertomilone.com/wordpress/?p=502

  [image: Hamster Indicator]

There is a lot of indicators, many of them have same funtionality as applets for GNOME Panel in ubuntu 10.10 and older.

List of indicators -- [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/list-of-application-indicators)

If you want to add a indicator to the Unity Panel, you have to install it and then run as a normal applications (from menu or via terminal), you can't add it using right click on panel.

Comment: When I follow the above instructions I get: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hamster-indicator : Depends: hamster-applet but it is not going to be installed
So I guess I should install hamster-applet?

Answer (score 0):

Good news: Hamster-indicator is coming to Precise, so you won't need to use the PPA.  Thanks to Alberto, bojo42, and Jamie!

[Bug #686062 “FFe: hamster-applet should have appindicator suppor...” : Bugs : “hamster-applet” package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hamster-applet/+bug/686062)